# Any chance to reduce the size of this snippet of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

IS there any way I could reduce the size of the snippet of code below? Something like `if (!$('body#pagina_blog_1` to `body#pagina_blog_10).length)` Online javascript minifier tools do not help.

```
jQuery(function($){
    if (!$('body#pagina_blog_1, body#pagina_blog_2, body#pagina_blog_3, body#pagina_blog_4, body#pagina_blog_5, body#pagina_blog_6, body#pagina_blog_7, body#pagina_blog_8, body#pagina_blog_9, body#pagina_blog_10').length) 
        return;

    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: body is unnecessary in the selectors.  you just need the ids.  Other than that, give them a shared class to select on and call it a day.

Comment: Are you asking how to minify by hand?

Comment: Ok, never thought to use a shared class :) thank you

Comment: I have removed references to 'minifying' this code as I don't believe that is what OP is asking about, and is a misnomer in this case. I believe he is trying to make the code shorter, not obfuscate/reduce it's file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's an id on the body tag, you don't even need to use selectors as you can just get the id string directly and compare it to anything you want using a regex.  For example, you could do this:

```
if (document.body.id.match(/^pagina_blog_\d+$/)) {
    // code here
}
```

Or, for just any one or two digits at the end:

```
if (document.body.id.match(/^pagina_blog_\d{1,2}$/)) {
    // code here
}
```

Or, if you wanted to actually see if the number after the id is in some specific numeric range such as 1-10, you could do this:

```
var num, matches = document.body.id.match(/^pagina_blog_(\d+)$/);
if (matches) {
    num = +matches[1];
    if (num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solution #1 is perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can: `$('*[id^="pagina_blog_"]')`

For more details refer jquery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: This looks really good. Will it work for id pagina_blog_1, pagina_blog_28765, pagina_blog_sfdgsdf ?

Comment: Yes - see the link provided in the answer for more information, although using a class would be faster.

Comment: This is likely not very fast as it has to check every single ID in the document when you could check just the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really minifying, but how about just

```
if ( $('[id^="pagina_blog_"]').length === 0 ) { 
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a shared class to select on.

If you must use the ids for some reason, I would suggest...

```
!$('body').is('[id^="pagina_blog_"]')
```

The reason you do not want to put the id selector as the first selector is this would result in a complete dom scan, which is not desired.  However in your logic it looks like your only concerned with the body tag having it.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery selectors and you're not going to check for numbers at all, why not just use: `if ($('body[id^="pagina_blog_"]').length)`?

Comment: Would probably be all right in this case.  As a habit I try to only have selectors that could translate directly to javascript lookup functions to keep sizzle from doing as much work as possible.  It's been mentioned in the jquery support room, as well as documented on their try.jquery.com pages, that using certain attributes in your selectors can degrade performance.  Using the is() makes the work happen outside of sizzle so it avoids that.  Also is() returns a boolean.

Comment: Speaking of "translating directly to Javascript", that's what I did in my answer.  Not really any reason to use jQuery at all here since the whole problem is really just a string match on a known string `document.body.id`.